# How to wait for the element to appear on the browser before clicking on it in testcafe?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, ui-automation, testcafe

I am running into an issue, where the link takes a while to appear on the screen but the next step(which is to click on the link)executes does not wait till the element appears. Hence it fails. i tried adding wait time still it is not waiting that long. Not able to understand what could be the issue. Any help is appreciated.

```
async Action() {
   await this.t.click(this.Selector(".execution"),{ timeout: 50000 });
}
```

even tried adding
await this.t.wait(100000000000);

still it din work.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: you need to do waits. here are some sample codes but written in python:

https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/wait

Comment: You can try using visbilityCheck
e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62880176/12250510

Comment: Tried that as well but it din work :(

Comment: Please post the test code and HTML of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can add wait before clicking to the element in the testcafe.

```
    fixture("Your  Fixture").page(
      "<your URL>"
    );

    test("Test", async (t) => {
      await t
        .wait(3000)
        .click(".execution");    
    });
```

Is that what you need?